# Mostrar divs al hacer click en un radiobutton

Tags: javascript, jquery, radiobutton

> Buenas Noches tengo un problema, hice un radiobutton que al
>   seleccionar una opcion me muestra un div correctamente, mi problema es
>   que al iniciar o recargar la pagina me aparecen los 2 divs al mismo
>   tiempo, y solo necesito que me aparezca un div o ninguno y no los 2
>   como se muestra al ejecutar el codigo. muchas gracias oajla puedan
>   ayudarme.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Selecciona el/los grupos de usuarios:</h4>
<input type="radio" name="opciones" value="multiples" id="multiples"> Multiples <br>

<div id="div1"> <textarea name="query1" rows="5" cols="150" class="panel-body" placeholder="Ingrese el query de restriccion"></textarea>
</div>

<input type="radio" name="opciones" value="individual" id="individual">Individual <br>
<div id="div2"> <label for="ID">ID</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control " name="query" placeholder="Ingrese Id"></input>
</div>


<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#individual").click(function() {
      $("#div1").hide();
      $("#div2").show();

    });

    $("#multiples").click(function() {
      $("#div1").show();
      $("#div2").hide();

    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: agrégale `$("#div1").hide();` después de `$(document).ready(function() {` y eso es todo,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**LA SOLUCION:**

Coloca un `style="display:none;"` en los `div` que no deseas mostrar:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Selecciona el/los grupos de usuarios:</h4>
<input type="radio" name="opciones" value="multiples" id="multiples"> Multiples <br>

<div id="div1" style="display:none"> 
<textarea name="query1" rows="5" cols="150" class="panel-body" placeholder="Ingrese el query de restriccion"></textarea>
</div>

<input type="radio" name="opciones" value="individual" id="individual">Individual <br>

<div id="div2"  style="display:none"> 
  <label for="ID">ID</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control " name="query" placeholder="Ingrese Id"></input>
</div>


<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#individual").click(function() {
      $("#div1").hide();
      $("#div2").show();

    });

    $("#multiples").click(function() {
      $("#div1").show();
      $("#div2").hide();

    });
  });
</script>
```

Ejecuta el codigo y mira como queda con el nuevo atributo en los div

Comment: muchas gracias, funcionó

Answer (score 0):

Para no mostrar un div usa:

```
<div id="div1" style="display:none">
```

Para mostrar un div usa:

```
<div id="div1" style="display:block">
```

Luego en jQuery usa según necesites:

```
$("#div1").hide();
$("#div2").show();
```

Éxitos!